# load doctrine mapping based on symfony bundle config

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm creating a bundle with some mapped superclasses. But i also want to provide default implementations for these entities. There is a config entry for my bundle to set the entity class.

If the user changes this config value to something onther than default i don't want the default implementation to stay in the mapping.

Is there a way to achive something like this?

So basically i want this: if the config entry is the default value, than add my default entity mapping to doctrine. If it's not the default, let the user define their own mapping, and exclude my default.